# Custom Field Type or Logic in the View?

Tags: django, customization

Before I start on this project I want make sure what I am proposing is feasible.  There is an unusual requirements I have to satisfy.

The model and formModel fields have to support a comment field on **every** field.  I would like to be able to access them by `object.field` and `object.field.comment`.  At first glance, this looks like I should have a separate type of comment and then somehow link it to correct field but is there a way to create a custom modelField that stores data in more then one database field from one or more form inputs?  I would think there would have to be a custom widget to support this too?

If anyone has any ideas or examples of anything like this please respond.

Comment: if you search on SO for MultiValueField you should get something related to your needs

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer to my question.  I have not tried it yet, but from the description it looks like what I need.   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#multiwidget